# Getting 405 when page redirected in angular 7

Tags: angular, http-status-code-405

I am getting  **405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.**  while page is redirected.

Payment gateway is redirecting to my page on success or failure that redirected page shows 405 error in browser...

please help me how to handle this in angular...

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: updated my question please check..

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 405 is because you are calling an URL with the wrong method. For example, a GET endpoint with a POST call, or vice versa. 
Ensure you use the correct method in the HttpService to call your endpoint.

Comment: payment gateway is redirecting to my page on payment success... that time in browser is displays like 405 error